# Is it necessary to use virtualenv to use Flask framework?

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I just started exploring Flask. Earlier I tried to explore Django but found it a bit complicated. However, Installing Flask requires us to install virtualenv first which, As I can recall, is not required in the case of Django.

In case it is not required, how to go ahead without virtualenv?

Comment: Neither Flask nor Django require the use of a virtualenv. However, there is rarely a reason not to use one, and absolutely every reason to do so. You should.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there is no requirement to use a virtualenv. No project ever would require you to use one; it is just a method of insulating a collection of Python libraries from other projects.

I personally do *strongly* recommend you use a virtualenv, because it makes it much, much easier to swap out versions of libraries and not affect other Python projects.

Without a virtualenv, you just continue with installing the dependencies, and they'll end up in your system libraries collection. Installing the `Flask` project with `pip` will pull in a few other packages, such as `Werkzeug`, `Jinja2` and `itsdangerous`. These would all be installed 'globally'.

Comment: The thing is that I am just learning/exploring stuffs. No serious or real project. But I guess I should go ahead with virtualenv. After all, I am just learning and using virtualenv is part of learning. It might help in real projects.

Comment: @mayankkaizen: a virtualenv is *ideal* when just learning and exploring.

Comment: Thanks. I have installed virtualenv and through it Flask as well. Good to go.